# Объекты, массив в массиве. Как вывести значение?

Tags: php, php7

Получаю ответ вида:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 239,
        "items": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
    }
}
```

Использую `json_decode()` чтобы преобразовать ответ.

Нужно вернуть значения которые в `"items": [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]`

Использую `return $obj->{'response'}->{'items'}->{'id'}` не работает.

> // syntax error, unexpected '{'

А `count` значение выводит `return $obj->{'response'}->{'count'}`

> // 239

Как-же вывести значения из `items`?

Comment: `$obj->response->items[0]->`, `$obj->response->items[1]->`, ...

Comment: @Visman $obj->response->items[1]->id помогло, сяпки С:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерпретатор совершенно верно вам замечает, что у вас не ожидаемая фигурная скобка, так как скорее всего, никакого поля с именем `id` у вас нет. При обращении к `$obj->{'response'}->{'items'}` скорее всего вы получаете просто набор значений, который я бы вам предложил получить либо как массив целиком:

```
(array)($obj->response->items)
```

либо обращаясь к определенному элементу этого массива, например так:

```
$obj->response->items[1]
```

*Примечание: фигурные скобки тут не нужны, пока что в получаемом вами ответе не будет чего-либо, нарушающего соглашения об именовании переменных в `php`. Например, если у вас в полученном `json` есть переменная с именем, содержащим дефис, то использовать ее нужно как раз не как `$obj->some-var->items[1]`, а как `$obj->{'some-var'}->items[1]`.*

Comment: items это некий массив объектов. В первом и во втором случае, данные не возвращаются, но ошибки нет. Что-то типа: `{
"response": {
"count": 239,
"items": [{
"id": 2943}]}}`

Comment: @ДанилПолянский В таком случае, вам все равно нужно обращаться подобным образом: `$obj->response->items[1]->id`. Ну или по любому другому индексу. Суть в том, что `php` не поймет, что у вас где-то есть "некий массив" объектов на том или ином уровне вложения `json`, который нужно автоматически преобразовать из набора его значений в массив с индексами типа 'id' (или именованный как id), для него все эти вещи просто набор либо переменных, либо набор значений в обычном массиве.

Comment: @ДанилПолянский, а, скорее всего более верный для вас вариант будет возвращать не просто `$obj->response->items`, а `(array)($obj->response->items)` - это приведет возвращаемое вами значение к типу array.